the asynchronous Python program is blocked
i decided to write a telegram bot on aiogram with the implementation of the qwen 2.5 math neural network via the gradioc_lient api.
The problem is that when there is an Api request, the asynchronous program is blocked and the bot stops responding until it produces a result.
Is there any way to fix this?
import uuid
from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
from aiogram.types import Message
from gradio_client import Client, handle_file

start_router = Router()

async def image_hueta(fileName):
    client = Client("Qwen/Qwen2-Math-Demo")
    result = client.predict(
        image=handle_file(fileName),
        sketchpad={"background": handle_file(
            'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gradio-app/gradio/main/test/test_files/bus.png'), "layers": [],
            "composite": None},
        question="доказать равенсво",
        api_name="/math_chat_bot"
    )
    return result

@start_router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Хай!!!")

@start_router.message(F.photo)
async def send_photo(message: Message):
    local_filename = f"{uuid.uuid4()}.png"
    await message.bot.download(file = message.photo[-1].file_id, destination=local_filename)
    await message.answer("Ваш запрос обрабатывается...")
    result = await image_hueta(local_filename)
    await message.answer(f"{result}")


What kind of "response" would you expect w/o a result?
